# Can not get this button to center align

Tags: html, css

This is the button:

```
.button {
width: 210px;
background-color: lightgray; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
input.button {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And this:

```
#buttonone {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

And many other things. What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what's around your button in the html. But you might try `display: block` to center using margins.

Comment: whats this about `lightgray; /* Green */` :-0

Comment: If you want to use an input as an inline Element, like it is by default, you would need to put it inside a block-level Element, then `text-align:center` the block-level Element.

Comment: What do you mean by a block-level element?

Comment: `block-level` Elements like a div, as long as they have content and no width, will take up their parent width all the way to the padding, and they cause a line break. `inline` Elements do not cause a line break and `auto` margins don't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `display:block` and `margin:0 auto` it should work just fine:

```css
.button {
margin:0 auto;
display:block;

width: 210px;
background-color: lightgray;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin auto does not work on inline-elements, but on block-levele elements.

Setting the width of a block-level element will prevent it from stretching out to the edges of its container to the left and right. Then, you can set the left and right margins to auto to horizontally center that element within its container. The element will take up the width you specify, then the remaining space will be split evenly between the two margins.

You can use text-align: center instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
// You should always use exteral code, when possible, for caching reasons.
var doc, bod, I, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var out = I('out');
I('btn').onclick = function(){
  out.innerHTML = 'Wow, you clicked the button!';
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#fff; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
.cntr{
  text-align:center;
}
#btn{
  width:210px; background:lightgray; color:white;
  font-size:16px; padding:15px 20px; border:0; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>test</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='cntr'>
      <input id='btn' type='button' value='Click Me' />
      <div id='out'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```